# data binding with knockout foreach is not working

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I am new to knockout and trying to bind data to `foreach` loop using `observableArray`

Below is my JS and HTML code, can someone look at it and help me with it where am i going wrong? My main issue is `foreach` is not working as expected

JS Code

```
define(function(require) {
    var app = require('durandal/app');
    var ko = require('knockout');
    var todoList = ko.observableArray([new Todo("test")]);
    return {
        todoName: ko.observable(),
        createTodo: function() {
            todoList.push(new Todo(this.todoName()));
            console.log(todoList().length);
        }
    };

    function Todo(name) {
        return {
            todoName: ko.observable(name)
        };
    }
});
```

My Html Code

```
<section>
    <h2>Create Todo</h2>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <fieldset>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: todoName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn" data-bind="click: createTodo, enable: todoName">Click Me</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</section>

<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: todoList">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label data-bind="text: todoName"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you doing your ko.applyBindings() ?

Comment: actually i am following [this](http://durandaljs.com/get-started.html) example and pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout is looking for `todoList` inside the object you use in `ko.applyBindings`. Instead of creating a variable, make it a property of the object being returned.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
function Todo(name) {
  return {
    todoName: ko.observable(name)
  };
}

function TodoViewModel() {
  return {
    todoList: ko.observableArray([new Todo("test")]),
    todoName: ko.observable(),
    createTodo: function() {
      this.todoList.push(new Todo(this.todoName()));
      console.log(this.todoList().length);
    }
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(TodoViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h2>Create Todo</h2>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <fieldset>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: todoName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn" data-bind="click: createTodo, enable: todoName">Click Me</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</section>

<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: todoList">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label data-bind="text: todoName"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.i have changed my code and put `todoList` into return statement and everything is working fine now, but i still have one doubt if you can answer, whenever i apply any class on this `<label data-bind="text: todoName" class='label'></label>` label it stopped working do you have any idea why ?

Comment: in your code snipet it is working fine but can you please check it with my way ? it is not working for me

Comment: That's just a class. That should not be a problem ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5gbLkt3/)). Does `label` class have any `display:none` by any chance?

Comment: don't know but it is something weird it is working sometime and sometimes not!